# Python signal from celery task

Tags: python, celery

I am running a celery task which on success runs subtask to send signal.

```
@celery.task(name='sendmail')
def send_async_email(msg):
    return mail.send(msg)

def send_mail(msg):
    // do some processing
    send_async_email.apply_async((msg,), link=send_email_signal.s(msg))

@celery.task
def send_email_signal(result, email_type, msg):
    email_sent_signal.send(msg, email_type=email_type)

signals.email_sent_signal.connect(track.track_emails_sent)

def track_emails_sent(msg):
    // adds logs to logging system
```

Problem is when i send email everything works expected but I see duplicate entry in my logging system.
I receive 1 email as expected, as per celery flower `send_email_signal` ran once. But in logs we have 2 log entries.
I have multiple celery workers running in the celery box. Want to understand how the python signal sent from celery callback task is handled.